# Ionic app doesn't ask permission to access location while installing

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova

I've followed the following steps to create an app:

```
ionic start ionic-maps blank
cd ionic-maps
ionic setup sass
ionic io init
ionic platform add android
bower install ngCordova
```

Added the following lines to index.html:

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Changed app.js to include ngCordova:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'ngCordova'])
```

Installed the geolocation plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

app.js:

```
.state('app.location', {
  url: '/location',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/location.html',
      controller: 'LocationCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

location.html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Search">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>Location: {{location}}</h1>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controllers.js:

```
.controller('LocationCtrl', function($scope, $state, $cordovaGeolocation) {
  $scope.location = 'Waiting';

  var options = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
  $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log(lat, lng);
    $scope.location = lat + ' ' + lng;
  }, function(error) {
    console.log('Could not get location: ', error);
    $scope.location = 'Could not get location: ' + error + ' :: ' + JSON.stringify(error);
  });
})
```

If I open the /location endpoint in my phone's browser (using `ionic serve`) I'm shown my current location correctly. So far everything works as expected.

/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml has the following lines in it:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I'm building the app using the new cloud package builder using `ionic package build android`. `ionic package list` shows that the build was successful.

I expected that I'll be asked for location permission while installing the app from apk. But I'm only asked for `full network access`. On visiting the `/locations` screen I get an error `[object PositionError`. `json.stringify(error)` is `{}` and `Object.keys(error).length` is `0`.

Using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` instead of `$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition` doesn't help.

`alert(error.code)` is `2` and `alert(error.message)` is `application does not have sufficient geolocation permisions.`

PS: I've ensured that GPS is enabled and it works on other apps.

Comment: Im having the same problem also, turns out its something with the latest Cordova update and and Android 6.0. So far from what I found out you need to access the api though an https://* address. However ionic serves/ runs on http. I'm trying to find a way to "pin" an ssl to the mobile. Its either that or host the application through the cloud. Apparently you can pin an untrusted self signed certificate but, i haven't had much luck.  I've been at this for 4 days now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation` with `--save` option i.e. `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation --save` so that the plugin gets added to `config.xml`.

Alt: adding `"cordova-plugin-geolocation"` to `"cordovaPlugins"` in `package.json` also solves the issue but has been deprecated.

Comment: i have already added but its only ask for permission and not enable GPS hardware.